# Changing from 1st Person to 2nd Person in the same paragraph?

Tags: speech

I want to know if it's okay to change from 1st person (our,we) to 2nd person (you, your) in the same paragraph as follows:

TV need not dictate our lives. There is a choice. We can either submit ourselves to continue living in the ‘twilight zone’ or choose to unplug and live in the real zone.  There are plenty of full filling activities waiting to be explored.  Whether it’s a new hobby, learning a new language, bonding with family or reading a good book – you may be surprised by how enriched your life becomes.    What’s more, if you have children they may one day, thank you dearly for replacing...

Comment: I had to scan carefully to pick up on *your **life becomes*** (which could have been *your **lives become***). I don't suppose the average reader would notice *either* the 1st/2nd person or the plural/singular switch in this context.

Comment: Shifting focus within paragraphs is completely okay. Within sentences is where it becomes an issue. For you, you're addressing a problem with society, which you then turn to apply to the reader. A great technique in my opinion.

Comment: In case you want some suggestions from writers on this, we got an SE subexchange dedicated to writers and writing styles: http://writers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thank you all for your valuable feedback. It seems there's consensus that its okay to use this shift.

Comment: Thanks Nate for the tip, I'll check the Writers Exchange

Comment: @NateKerkhofs Does Writers Exchange allow one to post a complete article for proofreading and feedback?  (Unfortunately since I'm a ne user they won't let me ask this question on the meta page)

Comment: @Newbie They expressly do not do proofreading. W.SE is more about general writing concepts and tricks on how to write.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't find anything strange in it simply because, from a very general "our", you're turning to address the readers, which is quite effective, as they begin to apply the suggestions internally as they read.

By the way, "fulfilling" is one word.

Answer (score 0):

One should try to not mix the various 1st/2nd/3rd-person voices when writing.

An effective form of writing (and exercise in the art of writing) is to try to never use 1st person (e.g. I, we), or 2nd person (You singular or You plural).  Instead, using the 3rd person active voice when necessary, but try to use the passive voice when possible.

For example, instead of saying:  "We think that...", trying saying , "It is thought that..."  Instead of saying, "We argue that...", trying saying, "It is argued that..."

However, above all, one ought not to mix the various "persons"-voices when writing - especially in the same paragraph.

Comment: I would agree in many cases where an academic or formal style is required the first and second person wouldn't
be appropriate.  However in my case where the aim to persuade the reader to action, I think second person is more powerful.
as explained here:
http://thewritepractice.com/second-person/

BTW, I use these viewpoints in my closing paragraph only. My entire article otherwise is in third person.